# DS 160 Marital Status

Tags: visas, usa, weddings

I have a question regarding the marital status on DS-160 form. I and my partner were married in the United States 2 years ago, while both working on J-1 visa as non US citizens. We don't live together and we are both from countries which don't recognize same sex marriages. So I was wondering what should I choose on DS-160 form? Should I choose single, which would apply to my home country, or should I choose married, which would apply to the USA?

I just want to be sure, so I wouldn't put the wrong information.

Comment: For questions about long-term visas like H2B, use http://expatriates.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @NateEldredge if I delete "as I am planning to apply for an H-2B visa" will you vote to reopen? The answer to the question doesn't depend on the type of visa being sought.